# Second mx records for transactional email of web app

Tags: email, mail-server, mx-record

I host an web app running on a single domain which sends 1000 transactional emails per day. Up to now i use hmailserver as an smtp server to send these emails. In addition to the transactional emails of the web app, i also configured multiple email adresses to cimmunicate with partners. Is it possible to split these two "types" of email use cases up and send them from two different mail servers with the same domain? Maybe with two mx records (mail.xxxx.de mail2.xxxx.de). Or are there other ways this is normally done.

Thanks for your help :)
Peter